# Angular routes issue

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am having problem related to routing with lazy loading.
Consider the following scenario.

**App Module**

```
{
   path : "deals",
   loadChildren : 'dealsModule'
}
```

**Deals Module**

```
{
     path: '',
     component: DealsContainerComponent
},
{
     path:':brandId',
     loadChildren: 'brandModule'
}
```

**Brand Module**

```
{
  path: '',
  component: BrandContainerComponent
}
```

The problem is when I try to access "localhost:4000/deals", It loads the `BrandContainerComponent` not `DealsContainerComponent`.

Is there any way to make it load the deals component first and if the brandId like "localhost:4000/deals/brand123" is provided it loads the brand component?

Comment: Where have you defined the routes of Brand module?

Comment: Have you tried 'pathMatch: 'full'?

Comment: can you share your code for the above problem?